# German translation of “Court and Spark”

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Court and Spark” is the title of a Joni Mitchell album and derives from a sentence in one of the songs, “He went looking for a woman to court and (to) spark.” DeepL gives me, “Er war auf der Suche nach einer Frau, die er umwerben und auslösen konnte,” for the whole sentence, so maybe, “Umwerben und auslösen“? However, I’m not sure that “umwerben” has the very old-fashioned and high-society connotation of “to court” which absolutely no one would say nowadays. (I nearly fell off my chair when my parents once spoke of their “courting” days.) Would “Hof machen” be better from this perspective? Many thanks.

Comment: According to the OED, one of the meanings of transitive _to spark_ is literally synonymous to _to court_: "spark, v.2 (b):  transitive. To make love or pay attentions to; **to court**" (my emphasis). One example of this meaning given in the OED is "I've heard as how young Errol is a sparking your daughter". If this is the intended meaning of _to spark_ in the song lyrics, the expression _to court and spark_ might be interpreted as a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language)), and an appropriate German translation might be e.g. _jemanden den Hof machen und umwerben_.

Comment: @Schmuddi - All three of the answers given so far assume the spark in this context is a metaphor for the glowing particle. But according to Wiktionary it has a different origin from spark=woo; one comes from Old English and the other from Old Norse. But I can't rule out that Mitchel's choice of word was influenced by the other meaning. Spark in this sense is archaic and other than the use in the song it doesn't really appear in the modern language. It might occur in certain rural dialects though, so perhaps taking a word from a rural German dialect would provide a good equivalent.

Comment: @RDBury: To be honest, my comment is a reaction to these answers as I don't really see the suggested "sparkling", "fiery", "flaming" metaphor in the English lyrics. So I checked the meanings of transitive _to spark_ and found this relatively straightforward interpretation as a synonym of _to court_. Perhaps I'll ask about the interpretation of this passage either on the English Language & Usage or the Literature stack exchange.

Comment: @Schmuddi That is so interesting. Thank you!

Comment: PS. I was watching 'The Beverly Hillbillies' to check on this. The word "spark"=woo is used in the Appalachian dialect spoken by the Clampett family. I heard it twice, once in the phrase "courtin' and sparkin'". TBH predates Mitchel's album by a decade so it seems likely she just heard "court and spark" and put it in the song. Of course how much of the TV dialect was authentic and how much was created by the writers is up for debate. Another thing to keep in mind is that the meaning of the word may vary by location; for comparison, West Virginia is about the same size as Austria.

Comment: @RDBury Wow! What a catch! Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention. 
PS: A search turned up this: https://blindpigandtheacorn.com/courting-sparking-in-appalachia/

Comment: @RDBury Go to  0:44 in the video.

Comment: @RDBury And this! https://open.spotify.com/track/5mvuFJzABrhrzS9gGTdqe4?si=4tg148XFToOvN0lM3h6S2A So you and Schmuddi were bang on.

Comment: I don't have a Spotify account, but I found a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdSUnseBMTU) of the song. I was expecting bluegrass but this this is more like jazzified rockabilly. All water from the same spring I guess.

Comment: Love this. Could someone write this in an answer? Comments are not a secure place for this kind of good information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky one to translate - You'd be looking for a concise translation that would also at least somewhat align with the English alliteration, but with a similar figuratively loose meaning. That seems close to impossible.

*Jemanden umwerben* and *jemandem den Hof machen* are close synonyms, and both would be fit for a translation (admittedly, *jemandem den Hof machen* is a bit more of a literal translation). Both would be fine as both are of a somewhat higher register and also somewhat archaic.

I have more serious problems with your translation of the other verb in that phrase - DeepL seems to have problems with getting the original meaning of "to spark" in this context (which also, admittedly, not the most common use of the verb in English in this figurative use), and "auslösen" doesn't make the least bit of sense to me here.

There are some expressions you could use to translate the second verb like "entfachen", "entflammen".

> Er suchte eine Frau zum Umwerben und Entflammen

> Er suchte eine Frau, der er den Hof machen und sie für sich entfachen konnte

The "fire and spark" image doesn't really translate well into German at all - romantic feelings in German are often expressed with magic rather than fire, so maybe "bezaubern" is the word of choice here, so

> er suchte eine Frau zum Umwerben und Bezaubern

Comment: wäre 'verzaubern' nicht besser als 'bezaubern'? Letzteres wird nach meinem Gefühl eher passiv verwendet, verzaubern hingegen aktiv.

Comment: @planetmaker Ist "to spark" nicht auch eher passiv (also, nach der Initialzündung)?

Comment: "Court and spark" is an alliteration?

Comment: @DonHolgo The nice round vowel sounds are alliterative, I guess. Also some nice consonance with the hard c/k and r sounds.

Answer (score 8):

You have to commend the English language for being so succinct.

"Umwerben" is quite old-fashioned, too. "Den Hof machen" is a more literal translation and even more old-fashioned, but also quite long. In my opinion, both work well in this context. There's also the verb "hofieren", but I would probably stay away from that, as it has a negative connotation nowadays of fawning over someone.

"Auslösen" for "to spark" as used by DeepL doesn't work at all, that's just wrong. "Jemanden auslösen" is seldom ever used and has a meaning more in the lines of redeeming someone or even paying ransom for someone.

What would work is "etwas in ihr auslösen", but it's quite weak.

There's no direct translation unfortunately that uses the spark metaphor, we only have metaphors around kindling a flame: *entflammen, entzünden, entfachen*. These are save to use metaphorically with a person's heart, you can probably also use them on a person, but there's a certain ambiguity left because it's not as common.

So a pretty literal, but long translation would be:

> Er machte sich auf die Suche nach einer Frau, der er den Hof machen und die er für sich entfachen konnte.

or, if you want to go full-on romantic:

> Er machte sich auf die Suche nach einer Frau, der er den Hof machen und deren Herz er entflammen konnte.

You can make it shorter but will introduce ambiguity:

> Er ging, um eine Frau zu suchen, die er umwerben und entflammen konnte.

If you find the flame metaphors too strong, you can use the weaker expressions "etwas in ihr auslösen/wecken" or "sie für sich gewinnen", but they're quite shy and might be too weak to use together with "den Hof machen".

Comment: Regarding the spark metaphor, there is "es funkt", but I don't think it can be used as an active verb.

Answer (score 4):

I will address three parts of your question:

> umwerben

"den Hof machen" and "umwerben" are both a bit old-fashioned but neither wrong nor awkward. I would use them both and I would prefer both of these over the "modern" *anmachen*, which sounds colloqial to me. Also - but that might be just me - *anmachen* has a connotation of hitting onto someone even despite the signs of rejection.

There is also "hofieren", but this is ambiguous: it *can* mean "to court" but also "to grovel". If you want to win over a woman you probably want to do the former, not the latter.

> "auslösen" for "to spark"

This is just nonsense. What you want to do when you want "to spark" a woman is you want to (figuratively) create sparks in her heart. "auslösen" means "to start off" or "to get going". There are no sparks in that.

In German - different language, different symbology - there are no sparks in ones heart, but the heart could burn (like "burn with desire"), hence you want to "ignite" or "inflame" it. The correct words are *entflammen* or *entfachen*. There is an idiomatic expression of "Schmetterlinge im Bauch (haben)" (to have *butterflies in the belly*), which describes the feeling you want to instill in the other. There is also the "[jemandes] Herz erobern" (*to conquer [someones] heart*), which could fit the expression. Finally, there is also "für sich gewinnen" (*to win (over) for oneself*), which could be shorted to "gewinnen".

This gets us to part 3, how to adequately translate this expression. Here is my attempt, which preserves the shortness of the original:

> Er machte sich auf die Suche nach einer Frau, die er *umwerben* und *gewinnen* konnte.

Comment: Vielleicht besser "und für sich gewinnen konnte".

Comment: Yes, that would be a viable alternative.

Comment: Many thanks to all for these insightful answers.